# How to Avoid Server Error 414 for Very Long QueryString Values

Tags: c#, webrequest

I had a project that required posting a 2.5 million character QueryString to a web page.  The server itself only parsed URI's that were 5,400 characters or less.  After trying several different sets of code for WebRequest/WebResponse, WebClient, and Sockets, I finally found the following code that solved my problem:

```
HttpWebRequest webReq;
HttpWebResponse webResp = null;
string Response = "";
Stream reqStream = null;
webReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(strURL);

Byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("xml_doc=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(strQueryString));
webReq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
webReq.Method = "POST";
webReq.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
reqStream = webReq.GetRequestStream();
reqStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
reqStream.Close();
webResp = (HttpWebResponse)webReq.GetResponse();

if (webResp.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
     StreamReader loResponseStream = new StreamReader(webResp.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8);
     Response = loResponseStream.ReadToEnd();
}

webResp.Close();
reqStream = null;
webResp = null;
webReq = null;
```

Comment: You are confusing the TCP protocol and the HTTP, which is a higher level protocol. Without more information it is not possible to know what the server is expecting. It may be expecting to connect to a TCP socket and write the textual data directly to the socket, or it may expect a HTTP POST. In addition your example URL is an HTTPS one, which would require an encrypted SSL socket...

Comment: You are correct that it is expecting a HTTP POST.  I'll google encrypted SSL sockets and HTTP POST.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use the sockets manually.  You can use the HttpWebRequest object to handle the socket layer.  You can see the answers on [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/566462/upload-files-with-httpwebrequest-multipart-form-data) for some sample code that will post a file.  Just change the destination URL to an HTTPS url for it to use SSL.

Comment: I started with this approach originally, but I was receiving a 414 error (URL too long) from the server.  I tried using UploadString and DownloadString with WebClient, but this also returned a 414.  Given your comment, I searched for additional WebRequest examples and I found one that worked.  I'll post the code that I implemented in the original question.