# The remote server returned an error: (414) Request-URI Too Large

Tags: c#, apache

I have small application in C# 4.0. Remote server is Apache2.

I have problem with error:
The remote server returned an error: (414) Request-URI Too Large when I send here data using POST method.

I try use this code to connect to apache2:

```
        String mainAddressWebApi = "http://myremoteserver.domain.pl/alias/index.php";
        private HttpWebRequest request;
        request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(this.mainAddressWebApi);
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.Referer = "http://stackoverflow.com";
        request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0";
        request.CookieContainer = cookie;
        NetworkCredential credentials = new NetworkCredential("login", "password");
        this.request.Credentials = credentials; 

        Byte[] byteData = utf8.GetBytes(data);
        request.ContentLength = byteData.Length;

        Stream newstream = request.GetRequestStream();
        newstream.Write(byteData, 0, byteData.Length);
        newstream.Close();

        this.response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();     //I get error here
```

Data should send using POST. Data have max to 2mb. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem once and the solution for me was the first answer here:
[How to Avoid Server Error 414 for Very Long QueryString Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2926467/how-to-avoid-server-error-414-for-very-long-querystring-values)
Maybe it can help you for very long Query Strings?

Comment: This isn't help me. I have this problem still

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue, except that POST was working, but second POST with exactly same parameters returned 414.

Setting `request.KeepAlive = false;` solved the problem